# Clear the browsing history on submit button click

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with a about 200 controls on it and Submit, Close , SavenClose and Cancel buttons. My requirement is to clear the browsing history once any of these buttons are clicked.

As of now I am redirecting the users to the Home Page once any of these buttons are clicked where the users can click on GoBack on the browser and come back to main page which I dont want to .

Can anyone help me achieving this , probably give me a start up code pls.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't actually want to clear the browser history (which you can't do with JavaScript, anyway). You just want to [prevent the back button taking users back into a secure area after logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579359/back-arrow-after-signing-out).

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to clear the browser's history for all sites? This seems like something that you would not be able to do through scripting since it should be handled strictly by the browser (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @Matt, Yes you are right , I want to disable the back button and the link you provided is helpful , however, I am using Session Variables in my code. How can I disable the back button on submit button click , pleaes help me with the sample code

Comment: You **can't** disable the back button, and you **can't** clear the browser history.

Comment: @Matt, I would like to understand the reason. Is it because I am using Session variables i cant clear the browser history or is there any other reason. Sorry to trouble you, but I am new to this...so i am trying to understand . answer would be helpful

Comment: I mean, there is literally no API exposed by the browser that you can access to clear the history, or disable the back button. It has nothing to do with the session.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**

This functionality is specifically within the browser's domain, and can't be accessed via javascript.  It is for this reason many banks and organisations log you out when clicking 'back'.

**You can** however [request the browser to not cache your pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z852zf6b.aspx), so clicking back will result in a "Cannot find this page - you need to refresh" message, this may be a suitable solution for you and is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think it's not possible to have control over a user browser functionality like "delete history".

You could add this javascript on the top of each webpage:

```
window.history.forward(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The user's browsing history is theirs to control. The best you can do is ask to close the tab via Javascript on the page after they submit. You can do this via `window.close()`