# not able to clear browser history after clicking llogout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have developed an application.when I clicked on logout page is redirecting to the login page by response.redirect.But when I press the back button of my browser i redirects to the previous page.I have used the following code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();


    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Also I have tried as suggested on stack overflow

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is not for removing a browser's history, it is to tell the browser not to cache the current page.

The reason why your page redirects when you click the back button is because the browser does not cache the page, so it re-requests it from the server. The server, then tells the browser 1) not to cache the page and 2) to redirect to "Default.aspx". Clicking the back button again, will again request the page from the server.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217256/clear-the-browsing-history-on-submit-button-click), it is not possible to clear a user's browsing history. Regardless of whether or not you tell the browser to cache the page, it still keeps track of which URLs the user has navigated to, unless the user turns the feature off or clears the history themself.